# How can i Make a String From Combination of String and String Variable?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
 string myconnectionstring = "Server="+ Program.server_address +";Database=rku;uid="+ Program.server_uname +";password="+ Program.server_psw +"";
```

`Program.server_address`, `Program.server_uname`, and `Program.server_psw` are global variables and their values are "localhost" , "myuser" and "mypassword", respectively.

But when I run the program, the value of "myconnectionstring" is "Server=;Database=rku;uid=;password=;"

But I want this:

```
"Server=localhost;Database=rku;uid=myuser;password=mypassword;
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the type of `server_address`? And have you attempted to debug to ensure they have the correct value?

Comment: Show us a bit more code, including the initialization of the other variables.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the line where `myconnectionstring` is initialized and see for yourself the values of the other vars.

Comment: What is *Program*? And why do you add an empty string at the end ("")? And use string.Empty rather than "".

Comment: here Values of variables is come from XML file

Comment: The rest of your code would clear up this issue @VimeshShah

Comment: program is a main 'cs" file where i initialize the all variables

Comment: all the variable are type of String

Comment: @chris Conney yaa only these global variable are bothers me

Comment: That's okay. Just show us where you're assigning the values to these Strings, and we'll move from there. Also, do you know how to debug in VS? @VimeshShah

Comment: yaa Cris i know here when i tried to store value of Program.server_addrss value in one String  variable but it gives the null value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format`

```
string myconnectionstring = string.Format("Server= {0} ;Database= {1} ;uid= {2} ;password= {3}", Program.server_address,"rku",Program.server_uname,Program.server_psw);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use `string.Format` for joining strings or use a `StringBuilder`. However, for forming connection strings, it is ideal to use [ConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx). As the initialization code is not shown, you can set a default servername and password so that the Program Class' properties always have a value. Also try to validate the connectionstring prior to using it in a [data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) (DAL).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you set the:

```
 string myconnectionstring = "Server="+ Program.server_address +";Database=rku;uid="+ Program.server_uname +";password="+ Program.server_psw +"";
```

before setting the variables:

```
Program.server_address   and  Program.server_uname  and  Program.server_psw
```

Change the place of setting the `myconnectionstring` variable after setting other variables.

Comment: We have no way of knowing that until OP posts the surrounding code!

Comment: @ChrisCooney: We can be pretty sure that OP either doesn't set the variables at all, or does it after trying to create myconnectionstring, so this answer is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: I never said it was wrong @Patrick. Just that the poster had no way of knowing if it was right, so it shouldn't be an answer yet.

Comment: i just said when i am in debuging mode in VS ...i hover mouse on "Program.server_address"  it shoes me the value but when i write this "string temp = Program.server_address " and now i hover cursor on "temp" it shows null value

Comment: set related variables just in previous of expression and test result